# Want to logout of ssh session but pvmove is running in foreground

Tags: lvm

**Situation:** I just migrated my disks from a HP MicroServer to a HP DL320e v2, in the process discarding an onboard backup HDD.  To replace it I've added another SSD that I want to add to my LVM VG.

**Problem:** I got carried away with all the changes now I have some new toys to play with (mmm bonding) and I started a `pvmove` operation on a PV close to 1TB.  It's going along at around 40 MB/s so will take just under 7 Hours to complete.  I ran it in an SSH session via putty on my Windows PC but I'd like to turn it off now.

**What I should have done:** Either use a local console (iLO) or use a screen session.

So my question is basically what can I do?

- Is it okay to stop `pvmove` and pick it up later (is `Ctrl-C` okay)?
- Can I send it to the background `Ctrl-Z` and then bring it foreground `fg` again in a `screen` session?  Maybe I should research that now I mention it.
- Should I leave the PC on? I'd rather save the electric.

I'm open to known good suggestions - I'd really rather not use my backups.

Thanks in Advance, Al

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay so looks like [it has been asked and answered before](https://serverfault.com/questions/55880/moving-an-already-running-process-to-screen).  Once I thought to write *background* and *foreground* in another session I had more appropriate search terms to work with.

The magic is done with `reptyr` - simply `apt-get install reptyr`

This is what I did (note I edited the lines to show which TTY the I/O is on):

```
(pts/4) /dev/sda5: Moved: 10.6%

(pts/5) # apt-get install reptyr
(pts/5) # screen

(pts/4) /dev/sda5: Moved: 10.6%

(pts/6) # ps -ef | grep pvmove
(pts/6) root 20618 13769 0 22:40 pts/4 00:00:00 pvmove /dev/sda5 --interval 10 --verbose
(pts/6) # reptyr 20618

(pts/4) [1]+  Stopped                 pvmove /dev/sda5 --interval 10 --verbose

(pts/6) /dev/sda5: Moved: 10.8%
(pts/6) /dev/sda5: Moved: 10.9%`
```

Nothing like playing with live fire (so long as you don't get burnt).